# Prevent Parent node from handling events too

Tags: java, javafx

I have a rather simple problem, but I can't figure out why this is...
I have a `Scene` with an `AnchorPane` as a parent node. This `Pane` creates custom `Circle`s whenever I click on it. This works as intended.
Those custom `Circle`s have event handlers as well.
If I click on a circle this event handler gets fired, but the parent's event handler is fired as well resulting in a creation of a new custom `Circle`.

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: It would help if you posted the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events are automatically passed to the parent `Node` (or to the `Scene` for the root `Node`), unless you consume them in the event handler of the child. To consume the event, call [`Event.consume()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/event/Event.html#consume--) in the event handler of the `Circle`, e.g.

```
pane.setOnMouseClicked(evt -> {
    Circle circle = ...

    pane.getChildren().add(circle);

    circle.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
        event.consume();
        // TODO: circle specific event handling
    });
});
```